# selecting max timestamp when timestamp is a text field

Tags: mysql

I am trying select the max timestamp value for a field that contains timestamp values, but is actually a text field. Before you say it, I can't change the field type because the app that populates it is not changeable. It's annoying, I know.

The format of the Timestamp is

```
Wed Mar 02 13:28:59 CST 2011 -> this is actually a text value in MYSQL
```

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Timestamp`, '%d, %m, %Y')) FROM `table`
```

'Timestamp' is referring to the column called Timestamp.

This just returns NULL values for the timestamp.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, also have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(STR_To_DATE(`Timestamp`,'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y')) 
FROM `table`;
```

Test case example:

```
SET @v = 'Wed Mar 02 13:28:59 CST 201';

SELECT STR_To_DATE(@v, '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this format

STR_TO_DATE(`Timestamp`,'%a %b %d %T  CST %Y')

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Timestamp`, '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y'))
FROM
  `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`table.Timestamp`, '%d, %m, %Y')) FROM `table`
```

Comment: this didn't work :(. I think the format of the string is throwing it off.

Comment: putting the quotes around it gives an 'Unknown column' error.